# Javascript: How to add a new polygon as an object and animate it?

Tags: javascript, graphics, polygon

I am trying to create a simple game. In which there will be 6 spaceships flying around and user will be able to select one and move around. I was able to do that.
Now, I want to add a new feature in which user will add a new spaceship by entering its parameters like speed, direction, etc. I tried doing it, but there a big in my code that I can't debug.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/fvtjzLhr/4/

I am storing the parameters of each spaceship in an global array called `ships`.
I am generating the initial parameters of the 6 spaceships by calling `addShip` function and passing parameters randomly:

```
var ships = [];

function addShip(x, y, speed, topSpeed, altitude, direction, id){
  ships.push({
        selected: false,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    speed: speed,
    topSpeed: topSpeed,
    altitude: altitude,
    id: id,
    direction: direction
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
 addShip(getRand(1, canvas.width), getRand(1, canvas.height), getRand(1, 100), getRand(1, 100), getRand(1, 100), getRand(1, 100), i+1);
}
```

To allow user to enter parameters of a new spaceship, I am using `<input type="text">` fields.
I am reading those parameters and pushing it into `ships`:

```
// Creating a new Spaceship
    var xd = document.getElementById('x');
    var yd = document.getElementById('y');
    var speed = document.getElementById('speed');
    var topSpeed = document.getElementById('topSpeed');
    var altitude = document.getElementById('altitude');
    var direction = document.getElementById('direction');

    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
        ships.push({
            selected: false,
        x: xd.value,
        y: yd.value,
        speed: speed.value,
        topSpeed: topSpeed.value,
        altitude: altitude.value,
        id: ships.length+1,
        direction: direction.value
        });

    };
```

**BUG:**

When user pressed submit button, a new very big spaceship is added. (I have no idea why, I am not using scaling at all):
[image]

When you select this new spaceship (it will turn blue) and move it around (press up, then down, then right, then left) it will become of normal size as other spaceships:
[image]
[image]

In order to debug it, I am printing `x` value of newly added spaceship in function `renderSpaceships`
And it is printing `1000000……` when user enter 1 of x. Remove comment of `startFlying();` to see it yourself.

```
//DEBUG
    if(ship.id == 7){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ship.x + " ";
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making the following changes in my code:

```
// Creating a new Spaceship
    var xd = document.getElementById('x');
    var xz = parseInt(xd.value);
    var yd = document.getElementById('y');
    var yz = parseInt(yd.value);
    var speed = document.getElementById('speed');
    var topSpeed = document.getElementById('topSpeed');
    var altitude = document.getElementById('altitude');
    var direction = document.getElementById('direction');

    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
        ships.push({
            selected: false,
            x: xz,
            y: yz,
            speed: speed.value,
            topSpeed: topSpeed.value,
            altitude: altitude.value,
            id: ships.length+1,
            direction: direction.value
        });
    };
```